# Looping forward items in an array

Tags: php

I'm trying to create a job roster for my Boy Scout Troop, and I'm having a bit of an issue generating jobs.

I've got an array that contains jobs for the people. I then use a loop to display a job associated with a person.

Is there any way I could have the job move one up?

For example:

```
Person 1     -     Job 1
Person 2     -     Job 2
Person 3     -     Job 3
```

That then goes to:

```
Person 1    -      Job 2
Person 2    -      Job 3
Person 3    -      Job 1
```

And then

```
Person 1    -      Job 3
Person 2    -      Job 2
Person 3    -      Job 1
```

But because users can change the number of people in a group (from 2 - 20), how could I make this process happen without hard-coding it?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what to try. I've seen the current, next, previous stuff for arrays, but I don't even know if that could help me. I've already got more jobs than people handled (simple check if more people than jobs, add more jobs saying no job and it goes down to 2 people and hard-coded grouped together jobs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can tell, you want to cycle through the jobs, while keeping the persons fixed.

If that's the case, you can do this in 1 loop:

```
<?php

$persons = array(

'Person 1' =>     'Job 1',
'Person 2' =>     'Job 2' ,
'Person 3' =>     'Job 3' 

);

//Get the 'persons'
$keys = array_keys($persons);

//Get the 'jobs'
$jobs = array_values($persons);

foreach ($i = 0; $i < count($keys); $i++){

    //Remove first value and reinsert it to the end of the array
    $firstValue = array_shift($jobs);
    $jobs[] = $firstValue;

    //Add the keys back to the array
    $result = array_combine($keys, $jobs);
    var_dump($result); //Do whatever you want to the result here.
}
```

Comment: That seems like it would work great. How would I go about looping data from my $names array and my $jobs array into the $persons array?

Comment: Do you mean you want to combine `$names` and `$jobs` into an associative array called `$persons`? If that's the case use `$persons = array_combine($names, $jobs);`

Answer (score 1):

- put the first element in a temporary variable
- run the array through a loop and set the current element of the array to the next one
- set the last element of the array to the temporary variable

Comment: I tried this, and it doesn't seem to work great for me. What would be the code in the loop to set the next element of the array into one above?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have two different arrays??? One for the person and one for the job?? If that is the case I would loop through the person array and then loop through the job array the same amount of times as the person array (starting at 0 and incrementing each time). This is assuming the people and jobs are equal. If you clear up any issues I may have in assuming this I can change my answer.

```
For i = 0 to i = person_array.length - 1 
   For j = 0 to j = person_array.length - 1
       int k = j // to show the starting point for the job so first time through job 1, second job 2, etc
       print person_array[i] " - " job_array[k]
       if k = job_array.length then j = 0 // starts at the beginning or the job array
   end for
end for
```

Comment: I'm not sure what language that is, or how to convert it to PHP.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$array = array('one' => '1', 'two' => '2', 'three' => '3', 'four' => '4');

$keys = array_keys($array);
$vals = array_values($array);

$vals[] = array_shift($vals);

$new = array_combine($keys, $vals);

print_r($new);

?>
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [one] => 2
    [two] => 3
    [three] => 4
    [four] => 1
)
```